# Adding name of weekday in pandas plot?

Tags: python, pandas

here is my code:

```
df["Created"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Created"])
df.groupby(df.Created.dt.weekday).size().plot(linewidth = 0.4, x_compat=True)
```

I would like to show the name of the day on the graph and also by which day the week starts in pandas?

[image]

Comment: Group by `weekday_name` and not `weekday`. Week starts in Monday, monday = 0

Comment: @RafaelC weekday_name just give me blank for the axes

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try dt.day_name instead of weekday

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html#pandas-series-dt-day-name